# Windows 10 is stuck on 1607 and "Your device is up to date"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have one computer in a domain environment that seems to be stuck on build 1607.    When I `Check online for updates from Microsoft Update` it checks and then tells me `Your device is up to date`

I have tried the Windows update troubleshooting tool.  At first it does the `delete and re-download updates`,  then `Download and install pending updates`, then gives me three green ticks for 'Fixed'

But after that, if I check for updates again it still says `Your device is up to date` after a few minutes of checking, and I'm still on build 1607.

Is there a way to force this computer to update to the latest build?

**Edit**  Normally I'd be ok with this, but the latest versions of Photoshop CS, Bridge CS etc are not compatible with this build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest version and upgrade manually with the media creation tool.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

It's possible that you are not being offered the upgrade because an incompatibility has been detected (drivers have not been updated by the manufacturer, etc)

Comment: Thanks,  I actually clicked on "Windows 10 April 2018 Update now available" and it said it was going to upgrade to the latest version (even though the page says 'April' it showed the latest build number) and after a while that has worked.  Your answer came first so I have accepted it.

Comment: FYI;  The latest version is 1803 or the April 2018 Update.  1809 or the October 2018 Update was pulled and not yet been released again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the [Media Creation Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/software-download/windows10) from the Microsoft Website to either create an install USB Stick (to update or install another computer) or update the computer the tool is run on.

Do note, the 2018 October update is not yet online, so it may help to wait a week. It was available for a short time, but Microsoft pulled it offline to fix bugs.

You can of course update to 1803 and update again in a few weeks to 1809 when it comes out.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. Small oversight on my side. Fixed it. :)